# Connection String Changed in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6, connection-string

I have the following Code for Connection String.

```
    If conn.State = 1 Then conn.Close
ConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=server08;Database=bmssmall1;Uid=" & Me.txtUserName.Text & ";Pwd=" & Me.txtPassword.Text & "; "
        '/Open Connection
        With conn
            .ConnectionString = ConnString
            .Open
        End With
    Set variables.myobj.conn = conn
```

As clearly seen, the connection string is properly defined.
However, during runtime, if I set a bookmark and check the value of conn once it has been opened, It shows only 'Provider = MSDASQL'. The connection string seems to have all gone.

please help, I have referenced this connectionstring everywhere in the application and not fixing it means a crash of the whole development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The has already been resolved on microsoft blogs.

[The Solution is Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/05/28/why-is-my-connectionstring-incorrect.aspx)

All you need to do is append  `Persist Security Info=true` in your connection string. And the problem should be resolved.

Let me know if that helps